# relate two tables by date, with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with a statement that I want to do and idk if it can be done, I tell them: 
I'm making a system where it's like a wall where all publications are users. Users can post things and can be seen by all. 
What I do is to give a publication share and send to my mind, in my mind are just my posts and I want this also publications which I have to "share". example of my tables ...

### Table publications.

id_publication 
Published 
user 
date

### Table shared

id_shared 
id_publication 
user 
date

```
SELECT *
  FROM publication
 WHERE id_publication IN
       (SELECT id_publication FROM shared WHERE user = '$user')
    OR user = '$user'
 ORDER BY date DESC
```

when I give a publication share, insert the table shared the id of the posting I am sharing, the user that he shared, and the date on which he shared. 
ok all right there, in my mind should appear only my publications and I gave her share. 
Use this statement:

With that statement I listed my publications and I gave her share by publishing date (all very good), but what I want is that I take the date of the shared table for these publications. The date that I shared and not the date on which the public, in addition to my of my publications. 
It would grab the date of the shared table for those id_publicacion (which I shared) and for others (that would be my publications) catching the date of publication of the published table.

Welcome any response. thank you very much for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite with a join instead of subquery.

```
SELECT * 
FROM publication p
JOIN shared s ON s.id_publication = p.id_publication
WHERE s.user='$user'
OR p.user='$user' 
ORDER BY s.date DESC
```

This will give you both shared and published date to do with what you will.

--EDIT--

Moving code up here to be more readable.

```
SELECT  p.id_publication
        , p.Published
        , p.user
        , p.date
        , s.id_shared
        , s.id_publication
        , s.user
        , s.date 
FROM publication p
LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT *
        FROM shared
        WHERE user = '$user') s
    ON p.id_publication = s.id_publication
WHERE p.user = '$user' 
  OR  s.user is not null
ORDER BY ifnull(s.date, p.date) DESC
```

Comment: Note that it's preferable to use the actual list of needed columns rather than `SELECT *`; however, the OP hasn't really given us names to work with, so...

Comment: Thanks Ken, but I only shared print, not publications shared the user.
I want  to print publications of the user, and also shared, publications by date and shared by date, all in one wall.

Comment: So I should assume you want either a) All publications by $user, or b) all publications shared by(with) $user? Moving your subquery to a left joined inline view should handle that. See my update

Comment: I think if the sentence I need :) but I mark error: 
you not have an error in your SQL syntax; Manual That Corresponds the check to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'p.data) DESC' at line 10 

Sorry for my ignorance on things SQL statement, I'm not very good at that syntax. But if I understand. 

Do you think this is something wrong accommodated? 

thank you very much.

Comment: thank you very much :) 
you just add the alias datepublication and userpublication to print them, and everything goes very well, but the field Published does not print, and I do not know the problem.   
Thanks for the time.  see the code, I edit

Comment: I can not edit.
here I will code
I wrote alias in two fields:
p.user as userpublication
p.date as datepublication

and print:
 $id_publication=$result['id_publication'];

$Published=$result['Published'];
$date=$result['datepublication'];
$user=$result['userpublication'];
but the field Published does not print.
have a comment?
thanks!

Comment: solved!!!!
was my mistake, I do not add a field in the database :S 
thanks Ken :D